# Relation between reciprocity laws and split places

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, local-field

Let $F$ be a (totally real if necessary) number field and $E$ a (totally imaginary if necessary) quadratic extension of $F$.

> Why are half the places of $F$ split in $E$?

I mainly do not grasp the relation between splitting and the reciprocity laws, I would like to relate it to the Hilbert symbol $(a,b)_v$, so that the product formula $\prod_v (a,b)_v$ for suitable $a,b$ would give the result.

So, is there any mean to characterize the splitting places by a property like $(a,b)_v = 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question is supplied by Kronecker's density theorem: in a finite extension $L/K$ of number fields with normal closure $N/K$, the Dirichlet density of primes that split completely in $L/K$ (or, equivalently, in $N/K$) is given by $1/(N:K)$. The proof is easy, but involves the fact that the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_F(s)$ of number fields $F$ has the property that 
$(s-1)\zeta_F(s)$ has a finite nonzero limit as $s \to 1$. It is a special case of the better known Frobenius density theorem.

In the quadratic case $L = K(\sqrt{\alpha}\,)$, a prime ideal ${\mathfrak p}$
with odd norm splits if and only if $(\alpha/{\mathfrak p}) = 1$. You can express this Legendre symbol in terms of Artin symbols and then in terms of norm residue symbols, and the product formula allows you to write it as a product of symbols away from ${\mathfrak p}$;  I do not know, however, what you actually mean by the second part of your question.